# iTunes Connect Screenshot 5"5 format

Tags: app-store-connect, screenshot

to submit the new version of my application, i had to add screenshot in 5,5 inches, 4,7 inches and 12,9 inches.

according to the "iTunes Connect Developer Guide=> Screenshot properties" the following resolution are allowed to be upload on the appstore

Screenshot requirements are:

72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency

High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format

Any of the following sizes:

640 x 920 pixels for hi-res portrait (without status bar) minimum

640 x 960 pixels for hi-res portrait (full screen) maximum

960 x 600 pixels for hi-res landscape (without status bar) minimum

960 x 640 pixels for hi-res landscape (full screen) maximum

But each time i want to upload a screenshot i got the following message: 
Les dimensions d’une ou plusieurs captures d’écran sont incorrectes. En savoir plu

without any additional advice.

Is there any other restriction on the format file to be approved by itunesconnect??

My picture is 640x960 72dpi rgb in jpeg format. 
I don't know what to do and how i can upload my screenshot to upgrade my app...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Looks like you are trying to upload the wrong sizes:

The following sizes are allowed/available in iTunes Connect:

[image]

From what you have written above, it looks like you wanted to upload **3.5-inch screenshots (640x960)** for the **4.7-inch iPhone**, but only 1334x750 or 750x1334 are allowed screenshot sizes for that category.

If you don't have a different behaviour on the 4.7-inch iPhone compared to the 5.5-inch version, I recommend using the Media manager and using the 5.5-inch screenshots for all other sizes.

[image]